# you don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache2, linux

Я знаю, что в Goggle куча ответов. Но мне ни один не подошёл. Я сам очень слабо разбираюсь в этом. По этому, прошу помощи у вас.Вот содержимое httpd.conf:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.phpOptions IndexesServerName 127.0.0.1
```

.htaccess:

```
Options Indexes
```

apache2.conf:

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lockPidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}Timeout 300KeepAlive OnMaxKeepAliveRequests 100same client on the same connection.KeepAliveTimeout 5<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>    StartServers          5    MinSpareServers       5    MaxSpareServers      10    MaxClients          150    MaxRequestsPerChild   0</IfModule><IfModule mpm_worker_module>    StartServers          2    MinSpareThreads      25    MaxSpareThreads      75     ThreadLimit          64    ThreadsPerChild      25    MaxClients          150    MaxRequestsPerChild   0</IfModule><IfModule mpm_event_module>    StartServers          2    MinSpareThreads      25    MaxSpareThreads      75     ThreadLimit          64    ThreadsPerChild      25    MaxClients          150    MaxRequestsPerChild   0</IfModule>User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}AccessFileName .htaccess<Files ~ "^\.ht">    Order allow,deny    Deny from all    Satisfy all</Files>DefaultType NoneHostnameLookups OffErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.logLogLevel warnInclude mods-enabled/*.loadInclude mods-enabled/*.confInclude httpd.confInclude ports.confLogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combinedLogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combinedLogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" commonLogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" refererLogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agentInclude conf.d/Include sites-enabled/Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да вы же сами указали в `httpd.conf`:

> DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

вот он их и ищет!

Закомментите эту строчку, и будет вам счастье!

Ссылка на доку (никаких гуглов не надо): [Apache Module mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html).

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем ясно в чем состоит вопрос. Если взять предпосылку из заголовка, то скорее всего вы не можете зайти на собственный веб-сервер?

Возможно вам не хватает директивы Listen [Apache Listen](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) которая указывает веб-серверу на каком порту работать и с каких адресов принимать подключения.

Comment: Я не могу просматривать каталоги не содержащие index.html или index.phpС этим же я связываю нежелание web-сервера отображать изображения.

Comment: Посмотри вот сюда, возможно здесь ты найдешь решение. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#optionsУ тебя стоит Options Indexes это нормальное для апача поведение. Возможно имеет смысл посмотреть активен ли у тебя модуль mod_autoindex